# What are the major differences between VB Express 2008 (pro) and 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I sometimes hack from some code for a friend. He paid for VB Studio pro 2008 but won't upgrade to 2010. He's happy enough for me to use VB Express 2008, but I am wondering what I am missing out on by not using 2010.

What are the major differences beteen

```
 VB EXpress 2010 and VB Express 2008
```

and

```
 VB EXpress 2010 and VB Studio PRo 2008
```

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Express limitations are best described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express

The best place to check and compare Visual Studio 2010 versions is this:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products#compareTable

Differences between 2008 and 2010 versions can be checked in a white-paper provided here:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/why-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a comparison between VBExp2010 and VSPro2008, but here's a comparison of 2008 versions: [Visual Studio 2008 Product Comparison Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=727bcfb0-b575-47ab-9fd8-4ee067bb3a37&DisplayLang=en)

To compare the express versions of 2008 and 2010, I'd say the best way would be to just find out what's new in VB. Here's a video showing off many of the new features: [What's New in Visual Basic 2010?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ff381705.aspx)